# Script run in terminal vs Script run via Desktop shortcut

Tags: command-line, bash, desktop-icons

I would like to ask what is the difference between executing script/commands via normal termianl window vs clicking on Desktop shortcut for terminal application (see the desktop shortcut at the end).

There must be some difference, because when I start command in standard terminal window and try to close during test command "sleep 100" there is warning prompt ("Close this Terminal? There is still a process..."). But when executed via Desktop icon, window is closed without any warning.

I'm asking because I'm preparing mount script for rclone that will be executed on demand after clicking desktop icon and I would like to keep that window open and "safe" from accidental clicking on close button.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Name=SOME_NAME
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Exec=sleep 100
Icon=drive-removable-media
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that `Exec=sleep 100` runs the `sleep` command as a direct child of the terminal process:

```
systemd───systemd───gnome-terminal-───sleep
```

whereas when you type `sleep 100` in a standard terminal window, there is an *interactive shell* in between. You can get the same behavior in a desktop application by wrapping your command in an interactive shell (it doesn't need to be a complex shell like bash):

```
Exec=sh -ic 'sleep 100'
```

so that the process tree becomes

```
systemd───systemd───gnome-terminal-───sh───sleep
```

Comment: Thanks! Helped a lot :)